# How to use a file content to complete a URL and then download the HTML? using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, batch-file, url

**EDIT:** I have a static URL that only changes in a specific area. **By using other file, I mean, to create a text file with the content that will be used to complete the URL.** The Python project should read a file that store the data to complete the URL per line, which content will be something like:

```
6565
567
8976756
3536364
4645454
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib2

# Open the urls.txt file for read.
with open('urls.txt') as r:

    # Read each line direct from the file object.
    for url in r:

        # Trim line end spaces and newline character.
        segment = url.strip()

        # Build the full url.
        url = 'www.url.com/very/short/and?simple=&url=' + segment

        # Read from the url.
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        webContent = response.read()

        # Open file handle for write, write content and
        # the context manager will close the file handle.
        with open(segment + '.html', 'w') as w:
            w.write(webContent)
```

If `urls.txt` contains the list of numbers, like in your edited question, then you
can use `with open(...) as r:` to open the file for read (read is default). The `r` variable assigned by `as r`, is the file object that can be read directly from to get each line.

The next line can use a `for` loop to assign each line to variable `url`.
The lines will have newlines `\n`, so may need to strip the `\n` from the line which is what `.strip()` does and will remove spaces on either end of the line. The value is assigned to `segment` which contains just the value of the number.

`url` is reused and assigned the full `url` including the `segment` at the end.

The next 2 lines are same as your working Python code.

The with `open(..., 'w')` open the file with name of `segment` with `.html` appended and the `as w` is the file object to use to write. So `w.write()` writes the content of `webContent` and the context manager that `with` enables will automatically close the file when leaving the `with` statement.

When all the looping is done, then the 1st `with` statement will be closed by the content manager. Using `with` as a context manager save having to close the object manually.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much, it worked! After some modifications to work with Python 3.6.6, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Below is your required code with comments.

```
import pandas as pd
no= pd.read_csv('Desktop/yourfile.csv') #Reading the csv file with one column containing your url endings



url = 'www.url.com/very/short/and?simple=&url='
for i in range(0, len(no)): #looping through the file
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url + no.iloc[i][0])
    webContent = response.read()
    f = open(no.iloc[i][0]+'.html', 'w')
    f.write(webContent)
    f.close
```

Comment: If it is helpful please accept and upvote the answer. Thanks :)